# firebase popup for custom token

Tags: firebase

I'm using Custom Token Authentication for my firebase app.

I will need to fetch the token from my server wherein the user needs to login first. I'm thinking of utilizing a popup.

But how do I pass to the opener (parent window) the retrieved token by the popup?

Comment: can i use a built in function of firebase for this workflow?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase authentication uses pop-ups *or* redirects for OAuth authentication because a user's browser needs to be sent to the third-party OAuth provider (Google, Facebook, Twitter, etc.) in order to authenticate.

If you have your own authentication system, the simplest and easiest thing to do would be to use form input on a page, communicate with the server via XHR, and then update your UI to reflect that the user is now authenticated.

That said, if you're set on using a a new browser window / pop-up for authentication, check out Mozilla's open-source library [github.com/mozilla/winchan](https://github.com/mozilla/winchan) which makes communicating between host pages and pop-ups fairly easy.

Comment: that library looks interesting. i even think firebase oauth popups is using that..

Comment: anyway, i ended up coding using the technique explained here to pass the token from the popup to the main window: http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage

Comment: @chrony no, it does not use this lib. Firebase has it's own popup logic: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/487f8e1d2c6bd1a54305f2b0f148b4985f3cea8e/packages/auth/src/utils.js#L264

Answer (score 0):

You may create a popup window for custom Firebase authentication as described in this example for Spotify OAuth: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/spotify-auth/public/popup.html

Also you may use in the main application window `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()` to listen to the Firebase user change event like in the example: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/86f9e135af344b2e9268c055a9a1bcb00a7e7c0d/spotify-auth/public/main.js#L36

How does it work? Excerpt from the [readme](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/spotify-auth):

> The ./popup.html receives the Custom Auth Token and other data back
> from the AJAX request to the token Function and uses it to update the
> user's profile, saves the access token to the database, authenticate
> the user in Firebase and then close the popup. At this point the main
> page will detect the sign-in through the Firebase Auth State observer
> and display the signed-In user information.